# Can you make your tag for your own language?

Tags: support, feature-request, tags, code-languages

> Yes, this question may seem like some sort of advertising, but its just so I can post questions regarding it.

I work with a few others to make a programming language called BPML. If you don't know about it, here are the links for it:

- [BPML Account (suspended)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14331977/bpml)
- [GitHub repository](https://github.com/JoyrenceMatthewAgas/BPML)

Since the main creator's account is suspended, I made this question.

He wanted that once the programming language itself is completed and released, he wanted to make a [bpml] tag just for his language.

> You can probably tell that he got suspended because he wants reputation for tags.

Since I don't want to break any rules on Stack Overflow and I still don't have enough reputation, I asked these 2 questions:

1. Is it okay to make a tag for the language that you made?

Comment: The language should probably *exist* first, and there should be at least one question on the site proper which deserves the tag for the tag to be created

Comment: Please ask only *one* question per question, especially if the questions are barely related.

Comment: You need at least 1500 reputation to create tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The purpose of a tag is to make it easy for *experts* to find *questions* to answer. Which means that in order for a tag to make sense, there need to be a non-negligible amount of people asking questions and a non-negligible amount of experts answering them.

If one or both of those are missing, the tag is just noise and cruft and contributes nothing.

The way that tags are created is actually simply that someone adds it to a question and the tag then gets created automatically. So, the above two requirements solve themselves: in order to create a tag, there must be a question to which the tag applies.

Note also that for this tag *specifically*, it would be terribly confusing since there already exists a much more widely-used language named BPML. While it was officially deprecated in 2008, there are still occasional questions about it. *That* BPML currently doesn't have a tag of its own, but any tag for either that BPML or yours should probably have a more descriptive name than just "bpml" in order to make it easy to distinguish between the two.

Comment: Alright, then I will call it Basic Scripting Program Language, or BSPL. If there is another one that's called like this, I will change it.